# jupyter notebook not found with spyder 4

Tags: spyder

After installing spyder 4 in anaconda, I ran the following:

```
conda install spyder-notebook -c spyder-ide
```

However, after opening the spyder ide, I cannot find the notebook tab / plugin.  Where can I find it?  Or did I miss a step?

Regards
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following link
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spyder-notebook

The following command worked for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spyder-notebook
```